# Open source social network

Tags: social-networking

I looked through the existing questions of this kind but didn't find what I was looking for so here goes.

I need an open source framework where people can...

Create user accounts
Invite friends
Have a friends list
Write messages to each other (some kind of inbox system)
Create posts on a standard message forum
Facebook login (Added, I forgot this in the original question)

On top of this I will create some kind of game where users interact, so it must be posibble to extend the framework with new database tables and functionality.

The platform is Windows, but other than that I'm willing to try pretty much anything.

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate as to why you specifically want something you can run yourself, as opposed to using an existing service.

For example, Ning (http://ning.com) would offer what you are asking; and although service is going to be for-fee only, entry-level fees will be fairly low (current word on the street is that it'd be less than 5$ a month). And it's fully customizable platform (via PHP).

And there are plenty of other choices, including completely free ones (bigtent, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) might have all/most of the functionality you need. Pinax is an open source project aiming to provide a generic but extensible community web site on top of [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).

I believe it has the features you are asking for:

- user-to-user messaging
- friend invitation (both internal and external to the site)
- threaded discussions

Besides these features, the platform comes with tons of other applications out-of-the-box, and there really are no limitations on what you can add on-top yourself.

While most Django lovers would probably choose a non-Windows platform for hosting their site, the [official documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/) does contain instructions on how to install on Windows as well.

Comment: Looks interesting at a first glance! Do you know how this would compare to Drupal?

Comment: @user: Really no. It is my impression that Drupal is targeting less technically inclined users, allowing sites to be built and configured primarily using the mouse. Pinax will require you to understand the core concepts of Django, and you will need a good text editor to create your site. In return, it will allow you to customize or extend anything in any possible way without much hassle. Then again, this is really just speculations from my side :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't use it, but check out [elgg.org](http://elgg.org/). Here is what it says about itself:

> Elgg is free and open source software.
>   It provides the components you need to
>   build a fully-featured social
>   environment...

Also take a peek at [opensocial.org](http://www.opensocial.org/).

If you don't want the hassles of maintaining yourplatform, but just want to create a social network and add a few extensions, you might be able to use one of the existing social networking platforms like [ning](http://ning.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Lovdbyless is an open source ruby on rails one.  Well written and easy to customize for yourself.  http://lovdbyless.com/

Answer (score 0):

I know you can implement all that stuff with [Drupal](http://drupal.org/), as I've done it. That might be a bit heavier than you are looking for, though.